# question 6.09 from Folland Real Analysis

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

I am trying to prove the following. I have also included what I have proved so far. 
[image]

How do I go about showing that there is some subsequence that converges to $f$ a.e. If someone could provide some guidance for the second part, I would appreciate it as well. Thank you.

Comment: For converging to $f$ a.e. try find a subsequence that converges very quickly on most of the space. For the second part, if $f_n - f$ doesn't go to $0$ in measure, find a subsequence where its norm is bounded away from $0$. from the first part, this subsequence has a further subsequence converging a.e. so you can apply the dominated convergence theorem for a contradiction.